# Would using activated carbon in a solar air collector help due to increased surface area?

Tags: solar-energy

Basically put a light coat of activated carbon on the collector, because surface area is so great, but I cant find info on its ability to collect solar energy, esp. compared to other materials.   Im guessing not because its probably a poor thermal conductor.

Comment: Solar collectors usually have a coating designed to maximize absorbtion and minimize losses, how do you think adding a layer will help?

Comment: You've increased the surface area but will capture the same amount of sunlight. Each of those microscopic hills will have lower incident radiance on their slopes than on their tops. It won't work.

Answer (score 0):

No, the carbon would just oxidize away. You add sunlight and air (including oxygen) to your carbon so you have all the ingredients to produce CO2.